# Prevent label click event as default behavior

Tags: c#, winforms

I have in a winform a label in a user control
when i click anywhere in the user control the user control is painted in blue

When I click on the label, The user control doesn't painted in blue , meaning it doesn't fires the click event because of the label

the label has no click event handler

Click on the user control:
[image]

click on the label: Nothing happends............................................
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event handler to your `Label` and trigger the click event of `UserControl` from there:

```
private void Label_Click(object s, EventArgs e)
{
     UserControlClickHandler(s, e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are working on Window Forms.

Label control has click event and it is inherited from control class.

So you have to bubble up event upto maincontainer ( in your case UserControl ) to change background color.

```
public void Label1_Click(object sender,EventArgs arg)
{
     // your usercontrol event click event
     UserControl_Click(sender, arg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I thought there is a property for the label to prevent this